# Hide page visual editor if template is selected - redux

Tags: pages, wp-admin, templates, visual-editor

The answer given [to a previous and identical question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/hide-page-visual-editor-if-certain-template-is-selected) is unfortunately not working on my WP install.

I'm using a version of the function recommended [there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35238/20094).

```
function nim_hide_editor() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    $template = get_post_meta( $post_ID , '_wp_page_template', true );

    if($template == 'portfolio.php'){
        /*echo "<style>#postdivrich{display:none;}</style>";*/
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'nim_hide_editor');
```

I've included the commented-out line to show that I tried the technique of echoing the style tag mentioned in the alternate answer, and neither of them worked when selecting by page template. However...

Two things seem incongruous:

- I've looked in my SQL database via CPanel and "portfolio.php" is indeed the value stored in post_meta for the pages i'm trying to use this on.
- Selecting the page by $post_ID, and using `remove_post_type_support`, *works*.

  ```
      if($post_ID == '13'){
      remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
  }
  ```

I'm going a bit crazy - it seems like I've triple-checked everything. Obviously I could hide that editor with an array of post_ID's that use that template, but that won't work for future pages that use that template.

Comment: Ach! Maybe it's that the auto-ID generated by auto-draft messing up $GET_['post'] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me, testing with TwentyTwelve.

Using `load-{$pagenow}` instead of `admin_init` avoids the checking for the global `$pagenow`. See comments for further info:

```
// Run only when editing a page
// For new pages load-page-new.php should be used
// See: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L217
add_action( 'load-page.php', 'hide_editor_wpse_88886' );

function hide_editor_wpse_88886() 
{
    // Not really necessary, but just in case
    if( !isset( $_GET['post'] ) )
        return;

    $template = get_post_meta( $_GET['post'] , '_wp_page_template', true );

    if( 'page-templates/front-page.php' == $template )
    {
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi brasofilo - I can't vote your answer up because i don't have enough rep. But that worked for me - i didn't look that deep inside of admin.php!!!!

Comment: this seems to target a more precise hook at the moment of page admin load, have i understood that right?

Comment: Yes, correct, it only fires when `/wp-admin/post.php` is showing a `page` post type.