# Can I set a CPT title field to a dropdown with preset options if user is of a given type?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I am using the WP Property plugin so I have a Property CPT. I also have building managers who will be creating these new CPT posts.

Is it possible to set the post title field to be a dropdown field with a set of preset options for a certain user type. Something like:

```
if (user->role == agent) {
  // title field is dropdown
}
```

Comment: Maybe using a mix of [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/88886/12615) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88103/12615).

Comment: I decided this was going to be to big of a mess. Decided against it. thanks for the note