# How do I hide tinymce within the edit screen of a particular page

Tags: filters, page-template, tinymce

I have a page.

The page is assigned a unique page template.
The template will use a custom loop. This loop will not call the content of the particular page.

I'd like to hide tinymce from the user.

My preference would be to do this programatically, using a WordPress function rather then using css to hide the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried the functions described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91026/45893)? It seems to be exactly what you're looking after.

Here's a slightly variation of the function for reference:

```
// Run only when editing a page
// For new pages load-page-new.php should be used
// See: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L217
add_action( 'load-page.php', 'hide_tinyeditor_wp' );

function hide_tinyeditor_wp() {
// Not really necessary, but just in case
 if( !isset( $_GET['post'] ) )
    return;

$template = get_post_meta( $_GET['post'] , '_wp_page_template', true );

 if($template_file == 'specific-template.php'){ // edit the template name
    remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
 }
}
```